# Highcharts : Highmaps : Geojson map getting stretched horizontally not maintaining the aspect ratio

Tags: highcharts, geojson, highmaps

I am plotting a standard Geojson of Us. If i am plotting that geojson with other tool than it maintain the aspect ratio , but when i tried it with HIghcharts/Highmaps it is getting distorted or getting stretched horizontally.See the below picture.

Expected : [image]

Actual :
[image]

Comment: What is your source geoJSON? What are your highmaps configuration settings?

Comment: Hello ,  
http://www.dartmouthatlas.org/tools/downloads.aspx?tab=39

this is the source .. goto "HSA Boundries". 

and JSON

chart: {
                    renderTo: 'map-container',
                    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                    color: 'white',
                    margin: [150, 250, 150, 250],
                    animation: true
                },

Comment: Those are shape files in the HSA Boundries file. Are you sure your process to create geoJSON was correct? Do you have a jsFiddle to view your full options?

Comment: 1) I have converted those shape file to geojson by QGIS tool. 
2) Yes as i have mention , with other tool i am able to plot those geojson correctly refer first  image. I will try to create a JSfiddle for this.

Comment: You have to change the projection in your QGIS tool and re-export. Find a projection which displays USA in a more convenient way.